# How to fill select html form with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Help, I stuck in laravel in this part, my program keep return this error :-

> "Trying to get property 'unreadNotifications' of non-object"

and this is my controller

`$listYear=$this->report->listYear()->pluck('year');
 return view('report.penjualan',compact('listYear',$listYear));`

this is my view

`{!! Form::select('year',$listYear,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}`

this is just what i got from db
[image: returned collection from db]

Comment: That code looks like it has nothing to do with that error message

Comment: thanks, i solved my programs, it was my mistake because extends from another page.. unreadNotification came from different pages.. sorry..